# Python Dictionary get value of Key

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to get the *value of the key*, not the *key value* in a dictionary? for example:

```
d = {"testkey": "testvalue"}
print(d.get("testkey"))
#OUTPUT: "testvalue"
```

Is there a way to get the String "testkey"? I will have no way of knowing what the String returned will be in the end. Would it be more beneficial to use a list instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Nomenclature note: in the dictionary `{"foo": "bar"}`, "foo" is the _key_ and "bar" is the _value_. Talking about "key values" and "values of keys" is a good way to get everyone confused.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `keys()` function (used as `d.keys()`). 
 You may also use this:

```
for key in d:
   print "key: %s , value: %s" % (key, d[key])
```

for all the information.

Answer (score 3):

First note that `dicts` are not intended to be used this way. Anyway you can use a simple list comprehension and the `items()` method, since there could be more than one result:

```
[key for key, val in d.items() if val == someValue]
```

For instance:

```
>>> myDict = {1:"egg", "Answer":42, 8:14, "foo":42}
>>> [key for key, val in myDict.items() if val == 42]
['Answer', 'foo']
```